# Listen to changes in only particular object in a StateFlow of type List?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, mutablestateof

How to listen to only a particular element in the MutableStateFlow of type list? If we listen to the entire list, then all the Views that are listening to the list if changed would rebuild themselves which I do not want.

```
class ArticleViewModel: ViewModel() {

val articles = MutableStateFlow<List<Article>>( /* articles list */)

}


@Composable
fun ArticlePreview (index: Int) {
    

   val model: ArticleViewModel: viewModel();
  
 // Problem: Since it is listening to entire list. If the list changes, the entire ArticlePreview widgets will rebuild but I only want to change a particular item if some property of the current item changes in the list.

   val previews by model.articles.collectAsState(); 
  
   val currentPreview = previews[index];


    Text(text = currentPreview.body);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compose is usually intelligent enough to figure this out itself:
It "knows" the old list, an "knows" the new List, so it "knows" the difference. It should then recompose only the difference.

However, this requires working equals functions.
The simplest way for that is making sure your `Article` is a `data class`.

---

> if changed the views would rebuild themselves which I do not want.

While it is true that excessive amounts of rebuilding the ui is not wanted, you'll have to get used to compose rebuilding ui every now and then

Comment: I have come from Flutter background where state management is very manual. In Provider it is easily achieved by for example `context.select((ArticleProvider value) => value.articles[index])`

I just want to replicate the same in jetpack compose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `derivedStateOf` in your compose function like this:

```
val currentPreview = remember {
    derivedStateOf {
       previews[index]
    }
}

Text(text = currentPreview.value)
```

The `derivedStateOf` function efficiently manages recomposition of your user interface by only triggering updates when there are changes to specific data. This optimization can significantly improve app performance by reducing the number of unnecessary redraws of the entire screen.

Comment: but `model.articles.collectAsState()` would already listen to the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to listen to the entire list, then you should have another `mutableStateFlow` which will only contain single `Article`. And you should have a function which passes the index to the `viewModel` and that will trigger the new `mutableStateFlow`. So your entire widget will not get updated.

```
class ArticleViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val articles = MutableStateFlow<List<Article>>( /* articles list */)

    private val _article = MutableStateFlow<Article>()
    val article = _article.asStateFlow()

    fun selectedArticle(index: String) {
        _article.value = articles[index]
    }

}
```

This `selectedArticle` function will trigger `article` state flow which you can collect from your composable. And your widget composable won't get updated if your list changes.

Comment: But suppose there maybe multiple updates to multiple elements in the list? Let's say there is a bool in the Article data class that turns true upon a certain event on each article. These updates cannot be stored in a single separate flow.

Answer (score 0):

To change flow data you can use [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/map.html).

It returns a flow, to have non optional value in composable you can build state flow from it using [`stateIn`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html?query=fun%20%3CT%3E%20Flow%3CT%3E.stateIn(scope:%20CoroutineScope,%20started:%20SharingStarted,%20initialValue:%20T):%20StateFlow%3CT%3E)

To have cleaner code I use the following extensions - it applies same `transform` both to initial and mapped values:

```
fun <T, R> StateFlow<T>.mapState(
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    transform: (value: T) -> R,
): StateFlow<R> =
    map(transform)
        .stateIn(
            scope,
            SharingStarted.Eagerly,
            transform(value)
        )
```

Then you can easily use it in composable:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

val article by remember(index) {
    viewModel.articles
        .mapState(coroutineScope) {
            it[index]
        }
}.collectAsState()
```

In this case `StateFlow` lifecycle will be bind to composable. Note that `mapState` should be called inside `remember` to prevent extra work on recompositions.

Usually you can use the same technique in view model - but in case your `map` depends on `index` parameter it's easier to do on view level.